# Domain Registration API

Tags: php, python, ruby, dns

At my company I have to do a lot of domain registration.

Is there a way for me to write something in a common web-language e.g. Ruby/Python/PHP that would allow me to buy a domain name from my own custom web-interface? In essence I'm looking for an API that would allow me to register domains.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to create a web interface to register domains from a variety of domain registrars?

Most of these companies have published APIs or web services to allow just this use case, so you'll need to check with each one you deal with and find out what they offer, and how to use them. Many will also offer client libraries targetting their API, in a variety of languages, so your choice of development tools will be informed in part by the availability of such libs.

It's also possible, that you will find plugins for Rails or Django that'll get you started - but I haven't checked.

If you are dealing direct with registries, as distinct from registrars, you may be able to use their [EPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Provisioning_Protocol) implementation.

Answer (score 3):

I personally can recommend www.opensrs.com.  They provide APIs for PHP and Ruby.  With these APIs you can order DOMAINS, EMAIL HOSTING and SSL certificate.  See http://www.opensrs.com/integration/api for more details.